# Laravel 4 - Simple join with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel-4, relational-database, eloquent

I'm simply trying to join 2 tables with Laravel 4's Eloquent ORM. The tables are:

TABLE: PRODUCTS

```
ID | CATEGORY_ID | NAME
-------------------------
 1 |      2      | Hammer  
 2 |      2      | Saw
 3 |      1      | Apple
```

TABLE: CATEGORIES

```
ID | NAME
-----------
 1 | Food
 2 | Tools
```

Of course this can be done with SQL:

```
SELECT products.name, categories.name
FROM products
INNER JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.id
```

And this will output:

```
Hammer | Tools
Saw    | Tools
Apple  | Food
```

But is there an easier way to get the same result using Laravel's Eloquent, maybe using the build-in table relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a many-to-one relation in your models:

**Category.php**

```
public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany('Product');
}
```

**Product.php**

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
```

Then call:

```
$products = Product::with('category')->get();
```

For each element of the result, `$products->name` and `$products->category->name` will contain your fields.

Comment: It's also okay to use it likewise: ```$products = Product::all()``` (although not efficient). ```with( relationship )``` simply eager loads...

Comment: Check out http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many for more options and examples.